# Defining a custom maven lifecycle with JSR-330

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, guice

If I understood things correctly Maven3 completely replaced Plexus by Guice. Old Plexus based plugins are supported by emulating the old API, but for new plugins there is no need to use Plexus anymore.

There is a nice [guide](http://maven.apache.org/maven-jsr330.html) on how to write new plugins based on JSR-330/Guice.

However I did not find any documentation on how to define a custom lifecycle without using some `plexus/components.xml`.

- What is the correct maven3 way of defining a custom lifecycle?
- Is there any good documentation on that topic? (Something like the guide above?)